# parity check matrix of $\operatorname{ham}(3,3)$ code - struggling with $q=3$

Tags: coding-theory

I am confused about how to represent numbers when constructing a parity check matrix for a $\operatorname{ham}(3,3)$ code.

I know that the dimension of a $\operatorname{ham}(r,q)$ matrix is $k=n-r$
and $\operatorname{ham}(r,q)$ is an $[n,n-r,3]$-code with $r\geq 2$.

We have $n= \dfrac{q^r-1}{q-1}=\dfrac{3^3-1}{3-1}=13$,

and $k=n-r=13-3=10$

So the matrix will have 13 columns and 3 rows. I have the solution as this is a past exam question, but I do not understand how they got the columns as they did. I am assuming instead of usual binary representation with is base 2, it is base 3, but I dont know what this is called and have searched google and I am none the wiser. The columns need to be represented in lexicographical order.

$H= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \end{array} \right) $

which is a 13 by 3 matrix with columns in lexicographical order.

If this was in field $F_2$ then I would able to work the columns out as they would be the numbers 1-13 written in binary representation.

However, they are not as I dont understand what the base is and how they get the twos. Please help explain how this is done.

Any help much appreciated. Please write in plain English as I am new to coding theory.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All Hamming codes have distance 3, which implies that the columns of $H$ are pairwise linearly-independent (i.e., you cannot form a linear combination of two columns and obtain the zero vector, you need at least three columns).

Now, two vectors ${\bf x_i} , {\bf x_j}$ are linearly dependent if $a_i {\bf x_i} + a_j {\bf x_j}={\bf 0}$, operating in the respective field: here, $a_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ (not all zero) and the arithmetic is done module $3$. The above can only happen if either one of the vectors is zero, or ${\bf x_i} = {\bf x_j} $ or ${\bf x_i} = 2 {\bf x_j} $.

So, to construct the matrix $H$ the column vectors must be non-zero, distinct, and none of them can be twice another one. Writing all the ternary vectors (as row vectors) in lexicographical  order, and striking out the prohibited ones, we get:

<s>(0 0 0)</s> :  zero is not allowed

(0 0 1) : this will be the first column of H

<s>(0 0 2)</s> : not allowed, this is twice the previous one

(0 1 0) : second column of H

(0 1 1)

(0 1 2)

<s>(0 2 0)</s> : same as 2 x (0 1 0)

<s>(0 2 1)</s> : same as 2 x (0 1 2)

<s>(0 2 2)</s> : same as 2 x (0 1 1)

(1 0 0)

...

I guess you can go on from here.

Comment: Thanks this is great - could you please explain how the ternary numbers are calculated? i.e with binary we would have 1 = 0001, 2=0010 etc, which are powers of 2. Are ternary numbers powers of 3, so we have 1=001 but then I don't see how you get 2=010, 3=011, 4=012                                              I am not as stupid as I sound, I just have no idea how you calculate ternary numbers but I do binary! I have an exam Wednesday on this so its hard to learn something new so close. I didnt realise we got asked when $q\geq 2$ until i saw this past exam question..

Comment: "with binary we would have 1 = 0001, 2=0010 " Actually, that mapping (each binary vector is associated to a integer number) is irrelevant here. A binary vector is just a tuple (list) of elements taking the values {0,1} (and if the tuple has length $k$ you have $2^k$ possible values). You don't need to associate them with integers in binary representation. Here we are told (arbirtrarily) to order the tuples by lexicographic order (as in a dictionary), so that happens to coincide with the binary representation order.

Comment: All the above happens the same in ternary coding. YOu just need to consider all the possible $3^k$  tuples with elements in {0,1,2}, and sort them in lexicographic order (again, that would coincide with the representation of integers in base 3, but that's irrelevant, it does not help and might confuse you).

Answer (score 0):

The columns are ternary vectors, that is, elements from the vector space $\mathbb{F}_3^3$. In a Ham$(3,q)$ code, the $q$ represents the size of the finite field you are working with, which is why in your case you are seeing ternary vectors.

Comment: But how do I calculate a ternary vector? I cannot find any decent sites which explain this. Please could you briefly explain how one of them is found?

Comment: Given a set $S$, we create an element $x$ in $S^n$ by setting $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, for $x_i$ in $S$. So a ternary vector is a vector whose coordinates come from the field $F_3=\{0,1,2\}$. If you are asking how those 13 vectors are chosen specifically, then I would recommend this website: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~hongchen/m422/Chap%204.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I knew that already, can you not just tell me how one of those 13 vectors with a 2 in it was calculated please?

Comment: The link does not tell you how to calculate ternary numbers!